# VB.Net Field Population Methods

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

Disclaimer: I am basically brand new to VB.NET and ArcObjects.

I am computing some statistics as a component of a larger arcobject script.  I write these components to an ITable.  This ITable is added to the map display as a standalone table.

I find that I am duplicating a fair bit of code to assign a value to each field in the table.  This is not something I would do in Python and wonder if a better methods applies in the VB.Net world.

VB.NET CODE:

```vb
   'Populate the stats table with the iteration.
    Dim row As IRow = tTable.CreateRow
    Dim fields As IFields = row.Fields

    Dim fThres As Double = fields.FindField("ThreshDist")
    row.Value(fThres) = lStats(0)
    row.Store()

    Dim fCountR As Double = fields.FindField("CountR")
    row.Value(fCountR) = lStats(1)
    row.Store()
```

where lStats is a list of doubles, and tTable is an ITable object.

In python I would simply use a dictionary to map the index (as key) to the fields name, as value.  A simple for loop would take care of population using an insert cursor.

Does a similar paradigm exist using VB.Net?  Am I missing something obvious in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [page](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/bdb9558a-d78d-446c-a9d8-f35f9eb44a5b.htm#QueryDef_Cursors) is shows you the types of cursors ArcObjects uses and gives examples in VB .net